# disabling local cache swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to get data from my server with the following code. It works fine except once the data is cached locally it pulls data from cache instead of updated data from server. How do I disable the cache so the data only comes from my Server. My way doesn't seem to work.

```
@IBAction func urlButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
  
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
                   configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                    configuration.urlCache = nil
    
let url = URL(string:"https://www.someserver.com/info.txt")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    if error != nil {
       print(error!)
    }
    else {
       if let textFile = String(data: data!, encoding: .ascii) {
          print(textFile)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {self.textLabel.text = textFile;
           
        
        
        }
       
       
       }
    
    }
})
task.resume()
   
}
```

Comment: You are not using your configuration, create a URLSession instance using [init(configuration:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411474-init)

Comment: Thanks for your info. I've had a look at your link and I'm not sure what else I need to be doing. can you possibly point me to what I am missing in my code :)

Comment: You need to replace URLSession.shared with your own local variable and initialize it using the init I linked to.